# j2me program for NFC reading won't work after signing

Tags: java-me, nfc

I'm trying to make a small program that reads NCF cards (for Sonim XP1301 phone).

When the program is not signed it works but asks permission from the user for every read / write operation, or for NFC reading...

After the program is signed (with official Sonim certificate), it won't even start... Just throws message "Java application stopped", without any details on what happened...

I have no idea where to start to solve this... One guess is that some checkbox is missing from NetBeans "API Permissions" settings, but this is just a wild quess...

I don't think that there is anything wrong with my code, because the same happens also with sample code provided by Sonim - when it's not signed, program works, but after signing it just says "Java application stopped"...

(I tried to ask this from Sonim Support, but there is just total silence.)

Here is Sonim's own sample code for NFC reading:

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.contactless.TargetListener;
import javax.microedition.contactless.DiscoveryManager;
import javax.microedition.contactless.TargetProperties;
import javax.microedition.contactless.TargetType;
import javax.microedition.contactless.ContactlessException;

/**
 * @author parthosarkar
 */
public class TestNFCMidlet extends MIDlet implements TargetListener{
    Form frm;
    DiscoveryManager dm = DiscoveryManager.getInstance();

    public void startApp() {
        this.frm = new Form("Read Tag");
        registerTargetListeners();
        final Command localCommand = new Command("Exit", 7, 1);
        frm.addCommand(localCommand);
        frm.setCommandListener(new CommandListener(){
              public void commandAction(Command paramCommand, Displayable paramDisplayable)
              {
                if (paramCommand == localCommand)
                  notifyDestroyed();
              }
        });
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(this.frm);
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

    public void registerTargetListeners() {
        try {
            // Register listener for each of the supported types
            dm.addTargetListener(this, TargetType.NDEF_TAG);
            dm.addTargetListener(this, TargetType.ISO14443_CARD);
            dm.addTargetListener(this, TargetType.RFID_TAG);
        } catch (ContactlessException ce) {
            ce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void targetDetected(TargetProperties[] targetProperties) {
        if (targetProperties != null) {
            int NB_properties = targetProperties.length;
            for (int i=0;i < NB_properties;i++) {
                frm.append(targetProperties[i].getUid());
            }
        } else {
            frm.append("No Data");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I finally found a solution: I had to install unsigned version of the program first, use it for a while and then install signed version of the same program... Now "java application stopped" message is gone.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the phone itself. You might want to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Yes, I have already informed the manufacturer about this.